# How can I make a rails model searchable by the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I'm trying to expose a search feature in rails.  I want a user to be able to enter a string like `name:"john" color:"blue"` and get a list of ActiveRecord objects for some model that have a name attribute containing `john` and a color attribute containing `blue`.  I'd also like them to be able to use `and` and `or` and parentheses e.g. `name:"john" or color:"blue"` or `(name:"john" color:"blue") or name:"bill"`.  Ideally they could also use things like `age<20` where age is an numeric field.  Is there a rails plugin that does this.  I've was looking briefly at sphinx and ferret both of which seem to create an api for this but it was unclear whether they provided a clear text based option or if I would need to parse the search strings myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ernie](https://github.com/ernie)'s **[Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack/)** gem is a good place to start.

You will have to provide an intermediate layer between your submitted form and the Ransack code *(this would be a good idea anyway for security reasons)* to convert strings from the format you desire to something Ransack can understand.

If you check the [demo page](http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/users/advanced_search) and the documentation for the gem you'll find it's quite simple to create the sort of queries you're after.

Watch how `GET` requests are generated from the conditions you build and in your application replace the builder Ernie has in the demo with a single textfield accepting strings like `(name:"john" color:"blue") or name:"bill"`. Do some pattern matching when this field is submitted and build a proper querystring to pass onto the Ransack gem.

**Edit**

For future questions like "what's a popular gem for `______`?", check out [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com). If Ransack doesn't suit your needs, perhaps a gem in the [Rails Search](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_search) category has what you're looking for. I personally use Ransack for *exactly* what you're describing; providing a custom query interface for my application's `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing your own search class. I find that for each app I do, the needs of search change considerably and it's simple enough to create a search app that considers all the variables you might want in a search query, posed against any number of classes you want to search.

In your Search class, have it return a collection, in the order you desire, and the collection can be made up of object instances that the searcher may desire.